# how to find the high and low values in each 20 line in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find the high and low values in each 20 line from excel file

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: Can you please try to shorten your question? Too much info right now :)

Comment: Hello and welcome on StackOverflow! As it stands right now, your question is a bit hard to answer: you could improve it by giving us a small example, and by showing us what you tried already (even if it's in pseudo-code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to build a range that will move 20 cells as it is dragged down.

We can do that with INDEX and some math:

```
INDEX(A:A,(ROW(1:1)-1)*20+2)
```

Will return the cell starting at A2 and then as it is dragged down, A22,A42,...

```
INDEX(A:A,(ROW(1:1)-1)*20+21)
```

Will return the cell starting at A21 and then as it is dragged down, A41,A61,...

The `*20` is the jump and the `+2` or `+21` is the starting row.

We put them together to get a range of 20 cells that jumps 20 cells as it is dragged down:

```
INDEX(A:A,(ROW(1:1)-1)*20+2):INDEX(A:A,(ROW(1:1)-1)*20+21)
```

Now we have the ranges, we just wrap it in MIN or MAX

```
=MIN(INDEX(A:A,(ROW(1:1)-1)*20+2):INDEX(A:A,(ROW(1:1)-1)*20+21))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your question is little difficult to comprehend from what I have understand is you are simply looking to find the Highest(MAX) and Lowest(MIN) value from each row. You can achieve this by using MAX and MIN function in Excel.
Please find below link for the detailed video -

https://youtu.be/8Z6l6uCfTHc

[image]